# Summarising data in 3 month intervals

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have data collected roughly every quarter. I have a column called `date` with a corresponding `value` column. This is the date at which a future value was taken. I am looking to create a table / plot to summarise the mean values every 3 months (baseline,3,6,9,12,..) using the past 3 months data.

| ID | init_date | group | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-24 | A | 2022-09-22 | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-08-24 | A | 2022-10-20 | 18 |
| 2 | 2022-08-25 | A | 2022-09-22 | 13 |

dput of some data :

```
    structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), init_date = structure(c(19212, 
19212, 19212, 19212, 19212, 19212, 19212), class = "Date"), group = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), date = structure(c(19214, 19235, 
19236, 19237, 19239, 19241, 19431), class = "Date"), value = c(20, 
17, 13, 15.3, 16.3, 23.1, 17.9)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I started by taking the initial date column and adding 3 months to create columns 0 months, 3months, 6months, etc. To then try to summarise in-between these. However, I feel this may be complicating things. I can't tell if I should pivot the data?

If a date is between the initial value and 3 months it should be included as a baseline. If the date is between 3 months and 6 months after the initial value it should be in 3 months.

| ID | init_date | group | 0 months | 3 months | 6 months | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-24 | A | 2022-08-24 | 2022-11-24 | 2023-02-24 | 2022-09-22 | 15 |
| 1 | 2022-08-24 | A | 2022-08-24 | 2022-11-24 | 2023-02-24 | 2022-10-20 | 18 |
| 2 | 2022-08-25 | A | 2022-08-25 | 2022-11-25 | 2023-02-25 | 2022-09-22 | 13 |

In the first row, as date is between 0 and 3 months I think I want to record this as baseline. If a date were then between 3 - 6 months I want to record this as 3 months, etc. Then I can produce a plot with the x axis as baseline, 3 months, 6 months, etc and mean on the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways of doing it:

1. Using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)

Steps:

1. load package
2. create a dataframe of dates from init date to the max of the date column
3. join them, using the `join_by(closest())` condition, so for each date in df, join it with the date in the sequence we just created which is closest to it, while still being greater than or equal to it
4. group by this new g column and then sum the values

```
library(dplyr)

mdf <- data.frame(g = seq(from = df$init_date[1], to = max(df$date), by = "3 months"))
left_join(df, mdf, join_by(closest(date >= g))) |>
  summarise(value = sum(value), .by = g)
```

Output:

```
           g value
1 2022-08-08 104.7
2 2023-02-08  17.9
```

2. using base R:

```
df$g <- findInterval(df$date, seq(from = df$init_date[1], to = max(df$date), by = "3 months"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method using my package timeplyr.

`time_summarise` essentially groups by a time variable and one can specify 3 months through the `time_by` argument, which then creates blocks of 3 month intervals from the start date.

```
# Uncomment below to install
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(tidyverse)
library(timeplyr)

df %>%
  time_summarise(value = sum(value),
                 time = date, 
                 time_by = months(3), 
                 from = init_date,
                 .by = group)
  group       date value
1     A 2022-08-08 104.7
2     A 2023-02-08  17.9
```